# Proper way to receive a lambda as parameter by reference

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, function-prototypes, function-parameter

What is the right way to define a function that receives a `int->int` lambda parameter by reference?

```
void f(std::function< int(int) >& lambda);
```

or

```
void f(auto& lambda);
```

I'm not sure the last form is even legal syntax.

**Are there other ways to define a lambda parameter?**

Comment: Why would you need the lambda by reference?  Do you mean `const&`?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You cannot have an `auto` parameter. You basically have two options:

Option #1: Use `std::function` as you have shown.

Option #2: Use a template parameter:

```
template<typename F>
void f(F && lambda) { /* ... */}
```

Option #2 may, in some cases, be more efficient, as it can avoid a potential heap allocation for the embedded lambda function object, but is only possible if `f` can be placed in a header as a template function. It may also increase compile times and I-cache footprint, as can any template. Note that it may have no effect as well, as if the lambda function object is small enough it may be represented inline in the `std::function` object.

Don't forget to use `std::forward<F&&>(lambda)` when referring to `lambda`, as it is an r-value reference.

Comment: Templates can also improve I-cache footprint, by eliminating jumps to general non-local code (in this case, execute your lambda directly, without having to jump through the general-purpose `std::function` wrapper first)

Comment: This quote, _"if the lambda function object is small enough it may be represented inline in the `std::function` object"_ is misleading.  Lambdas are always available for inline (the compiler can choose not to of course).  `std::function` implementations generally uses small object optimization to avoid heap allocations.  If a lambda has a small enough _capture list_ it will be stored in `std::function` without using the heap.  Other than that a lambda's size has no real meaning.

Comment: @bdonlan: By the way, why is there `&` in `void f(F & lambda)`?

Comment: @jalf, indeed, it can either help or hurt. hard to tell which without measuring

Comment: @Nawaz, passing `F` as a const reference avoids copying the lambda object when passing it as an argument

Comment: @bdonlan: But the const& assumes that the members of the lambda (the capture-by-values) cannot be changed. Which may not be what the user wants.

Comment: @Nicol, ah, good point. I guess a non-const reference would be best here

Comment: @bdonlan It's been a while, but passing as non-const reference does not allow construction of a temporary lambda in the function call. An r-value reference would be best here.

Comment: I dare to say that this has changed in C++17

Answer (score 65):

I would use `template` as:

```
template<typename Functor>
void f(Functor functor)
{
   cout << functor(10) << endl;
}

int g(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
int main() 
{
    auto lambda = [] (int x) { cout << x * 50 << endl; return x * 100; };
    f(lambda); //pass lambda
    f(g);      //pass function 
}
```

Output:

```
500
1000
100
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/EayVq

Answer (score 48):

I know it's been 7 years, but here's a way nobody else mentioned:

```
void foo(void (*f)(int)){
    std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;
    f(1); // calls lambda which takes an int and returns void
}
int main(){
    foo([](int a){std::cout<<"lambda "<<a<<std::endl;});
}
```

Which outputs:

```
foo
lambda 1
```

No need for templates or std::function

Comment: this is limited only to lambdas that can decay to function pointers (lambdas w/o captures), and also requires to specify exact signature (same as for `std::function` case though) while templated version doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 12):

Since C++ 20,

```
void f(auto& lambda);
```

actually works (it's an [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template)):

> When placeholder types (either `auto` or `Concept auto`) appear in the parameter list of a function declaration or of a function template declaration, the declaration declares a function template, and one invented template parameter for each placeholder is appended to the template parameter list

and it's equivalent to exactly option 2 in @bdonlan's answer:

```
template<typename F>
void f(F &lambda) { /* ... */}
```

Comment: And as slightly mentioned, it would probably be even better to constrain F with some concepts based on the needs of `f()`

Answer (score 4):

> `void f(auto& lambda);`

That's close. What will actually compile is:

```
#include <cassert>

/*constexpr optional*/ const auto f = [](auto &&lambda)
{
  lambda();
  lambda();
};

int main()
{
  int counter = 0;
  f([&]{ ++counter; });
  assert(counter == 2);
}
```

Comment: Is the only difference between the OP's code and yours being `&` or `&&`? How is this different from the "abbreviated function template", which was mentioned in [@Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67718838/10027592)? Thanks.