# What is the proper way to pass lambda as an argument in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures

As far as I know, I have at least the following three ways to declare a function which accept closures:

1. by copying
2. by reference
3. by moving

e.g.

```
void FooCopyLambda(std::function<void()> f) {
  // ...
  f();
  // ...
}

void FooRefLambda(const std::function<void()> &f) {
  // ...
  f();
  // ...
}

void FooMoveLambda(std::function<void()> &&f) {
  // ...
  f();
  // ...
}
```

In [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458612/c0x-proper-way-to-receive-a-lambda-as-parameter-by-reference), people discussed how to pass by reference. But here I also want to know, should I pass it by reference? Or maybe I should pass it by value or moving?

What's the proper way to pass lambda as an argument? Why?

Comment: @Nelfeal That question is specific to reference, this one includes by value and by moving besides  be reference

Comment: Lambdas are **not** `std::function`. Pass them by a forwarding reference `T&&`.

Comment: @Evg, Would be better if you can give more details

Comment: @hxpax [passing lambda as argument - by reference or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373146/passing-lambda-as-argument-by-reference-or-value)

Comment: BTW, you don't "pass by moving", you pass by rvalue reference, which only bind to rvalues (typically temporaries). But `T&&` as argument of a function template is yet another beast, called a forwarding reference as Evg mentionned.