# Passing lambdas as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I am trying to generalize my benchmarking function, by having it receive the function to benchmark as the first parameter and the number of iterations as the second.

But since the function to benchmark needs to receive additional parameters, I thought I would fill in the parameters in the body of a lambda function and pass that to the benchmarking function. (I think that is called currying?)

Anyway I can not get it to compile:

```
main.cpp:43:62: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::function<double*()>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda()>’
   bench::bench([=](){rng::gpu_r_exp((int) 10e6, lambda);}, 50);
```

The function declaration looks like this:

```
void bench(std::function<double*()>& funct_to_bench, int repeats);
```

and I use it like this:

```
bench::bench([=](){rng::gpu_r_exp((int) 10e6, lambda);}, 50);
```

Since the compiler bickers about `non-const` again, I should maybe add, that `gpu_r_exp` utilizes a global variable which stores the `rngState` (it also did not like non-const parameters in `gpu_r_exp`).

I am really stuck. I just want to fill in the parameters and pass the pre-prepared function handle to the benchmarking function, so that it can wrap a timer with a progress bar around it.

EDIT: I should add that the parameter called `lambda` is a double, which is the parameter of the exponential distribution and has nothing to do with the lambda function.

Comment: A lambda is not a `std::function`.  You need to pass a `std::function` to the function since it requires a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458612/c0x-proper-way-to-receive-a-lambda-as-parameter-by-reference the accepted answer says that option 1 works, and that is pretty much what I used, right?

Comment: Your function is using a `std::function &`, that's not the same as a `std::function`.  non-const lvalue references (which `std::function &` is) do not allow for conversions.  You have to give it exactly what it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver what is an `lvalue reference`?

Comment: I'm confused how the `const`-ness of the function parameter relates to a global variable you have

Comment: @UnholySheep I first tried to pass the RngState as a const parameter since it complained about all parameters which were not const. But since it has setters (you have to change the rng state when you used it), it did complain about that. So I refactored it to a global variable. I wonder whether it still complains about that since the message includes `const`. I don't really understand the error message beyond that

Comment: @FelixB. In `void foo(int&)`, the `int&` is a non-const lvalue refernce.  In `void foo(const int &)` the `const int &` is a const lvalue reference.  In `void foo(int&&)` the `int&&` is a rvalue reference.  In `void foo(const int&&)` the `consat int&&` is a const rvalue reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver I pretty much just copied `void f(std::function< int(int) >& lambda);` from the linked question. I will look up what lvalues and rvalues are I guess. But shouldn't the same syntax work?

Comment: @FelixB. No.  Like I said: non-const lvalue references do not allow for conversions. You have to give it exactly what it is.  Since a lambda is not a `std::function` it wont work.  A const-lvalue reference does allow for conversions and will let the code work.

Comment: @NathanOliver `main.cpp:43:62: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::function<double*()>&’ from expression of type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda()>’
   bench::bench([=](){rng::gpu_r_exp((int) 10e6, lambda);}, 50);`

Comment: `std::function<double*()>` says the function should return a `double*` and take no arguments.  `[=](){rng::gpu_r_exp((int) 10e6, lambda);}` does not do that.  It doesn't take any parameters so you are good there, but it doesn't return anything so it has the signature `void()`

Comment: Oh right, I am sorry `main.cpp:43:62: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::function<void*()>&’ from expression of type ‘main(int, char**)::<lambda()>’
   bench::bench([=](){rng::gpu_r_exp((int) 10e6, lambda);}, 50);` I forgot that I am eating the return value with the lambda too

Comment: `void*` is a pointer to void. you want just `std::function<void()>`

Comment: Same problem. `std::function<void*()>` takes a function that returns a `void*` pointer, but your lambda does not return anything at all so its return value is `void` instead.

Comment: this worked .... thanks guys - I guess I am too tired for this. I should get some sleep

Answer (score 1):

Given that the benchmark wrapper is small, it doesn't make sense to worry about what's passed in, or whether it can be converted to `std::function`. Just take what comes and as long as it can be called, you're golden:

```
template <typename Fun>
void benchmarkCallable(size_t iterations, Fun &&callable)
{
  //...
  while (iterations--)
    callable();
  //..
}
```

If you worry that the `//...` sections are getting unwieldy, you can factor them out into a class:

```
class ScopedBenchmark {
  // start time, other state needed, etc.
public:
  ScopedBenchmark() { /* capture initial state */ }
  ~ScopedBenchmark() { /* dump results etc */ }
};

template <typename Fun>
void benchmarkCallable(size_t iterations, Fun &&callable)
{
  ScopedBenchmark benchmark;
  while (iterations--)
    callable();
}

int main()
{
  benchmarkCallable(1'000'000, []{ printf("foo!\n"); });
}
```